# Authenticate Django from url without login

Tags: python, django

I am trying to log my user with a link generated from me, basically this is the workflow, a user wants to fill a form from my site, but they comunicate through whatsapp, so i will generate a link for them, but the catch is they have to log in once they go into the page, since they will fill some sensitive data , plus, id like them to get logged into the system and use other functionalities if they want.

Security wise, i will always know if the user is who they say when they message me bc i can recognize the phone number, so i dont need them to log in again once they click the link and go into the browser. Dont get me wrong i want the user to be able to log in if they want from their computer, but it makes it a lo easier if they dont have to do that form mobile.

Based on the phone number i will know the user, so what i need is  generate a link where they will click and it will be self authenticating, meaning they will be logged with this link and forwarded to where they neeed.

I'd appreciate any recomendations or tecnologies to do this implementation

Answer (score 2):

You will have to send links with generated api-tokens that allow them to log in for a certain amount of time after you generate the link.
The link may be something like `https://yoursite.com/api?token=the_special_token` and then in your login View, you write a function to check the validity of the token against the user's phone number provided.
You can use on django's token module to generate and authenticate the tokens.